# Robot Framework: why suite setup seems not to be working properly?

Tags: java, robotframework

I'm using RF on java (through the Hi-Fi selenium-java implementation). I currently have a Java class where I'm implementing a keyword called Driver Setup to set the path to my browser driver.

Thing is, I'm supposed to be able to do suite setup and teardown in `__init__.robot` but something doesn't seem to be working as I expect. My suite setup would be to set the selenium driver path (my `Driver Setup` keyword). So I did this:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup                 Driver Setup
Test Setup                  Open Browser   ${my app url}  chrome
Test Teardown               Close Browser
```

However, I can't seem to be able to execute `Driver Setup`, as I get: `Parent suite setup failed: No keyword with name 'Driver Setup' found.` However, if I do a `Test Setup` instead of Suite Setup, it all works ok and tests run successfully.

So as a workaround I have to do this:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup                  Run Keywords    Driver Setup    AND     Open Browser     ${my app url}  chrome
Test Teardown               Close Browser
```

For context:

My java class that implements Driver Setup is placed in `/src/main/java/mypackage/MyKeywords.java`.

In the `/src/test/robotframework/acceptance` directory I have a global resources file. Also in `/src/test/robotframework/acceptance`, I have a directory with a test suite (Tests.robot), an __init__.robot initialization file and a Resources.robot file for high level keywords and variables.

This pretty much sums up my directory setup:

```
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───mypackage
│   │           MyKeywords.java
│   │
│   └───resources
└───test
    ├───java
    ├───resources
    │       chromedriver.exe
    │
    └───robotframework
        └───acceptance
            │   GlobalResources.robot
            └───someApplicationFeature
                    Resources.robot
                    Tests.robot
                    __init__.robot
```

I'm calling the SeleniumLibrary and my own library in `GlobalResources.robot`, since I want them to be available for all test suites, so I did this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library                 SeleniumLibrary
Library                 mypackage.MyKeywords
```

So... why doesn't my custom keyword work with Suite Setup?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that `Suite Setup    Driver Setup` doesn't work, but in the very same file `Test Setup    Driver Setup` works?

Comment: Exactly. If I change "Suite Setup" for "Test Setup" my tests run. If I leave it as "Suite Setup" I get the "No keyword with name 'Driver Setup' found" error. In case it changes anything, I'm using Maven to run my project (to automatically import RF and selenium dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

-Download the latest version of the chrome driver and update the chrome.

-Move the latest chrome driver to folder from where the path is taken. (Eg. mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin)